# beautifulsoup: can't extract all the elements in one loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

***Code:***

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div><p>p_string</p><div>div_string</div></div>')
for m in soup.div:
    print "extract(first loop): ", m.extract()
print "current soup.div(frist loop): ", soup.div #it contains another div block
print '___________________________________________________________'

#I have to do another for loop to purge the remaining div block, why?
for m in soup.div:
    print "extract(second loop): ", m.extract()

print "current soup.div(second loop): ", soup.div #removed
```

***Result:***

```
extract(first loop):  <p>p_string</p>
current soup.div(frist loop):  <div><div>div_string</div></div>
___________________________________________________________
extract(second loop):  <div>div_string</div>
current soup.div(second loop):  <div></div>
```

Why didn't it extract all elements(`p` and `div`) in the first `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are calling `extract()` in the loop which removes a tag from a tree - removing the tag's children while iterating over them. It is basically the same as [iterating over the list and remove items from it in the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10086849/771848).

Instead, use [`.find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
for m in soup.div.find_all():
    print m.extract()
```